# SQLite database in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, oracle11g

I'm working on a Qt C++ GUI, where I'm trying to insert data into tables in a database.

But this is the error I get:

> no such table: Writers unable to execute statement.

Here is my code:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

#include <QtSql>
#include<QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

QSqlDatabase db= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setHostName("FCOESL200656336");
db.setDatabaseName("ORCL");
db.setUserName("scott");
db.setPassword("lion");
db.open();


if(db.open())
{
    qDebug() << "Opened!";


     QString sQuery = " insert into  Writers(W_Id,W_Name,Age,Gender,Nationality,Hand_Used)Values(:W_Id,:W_Name,:Age,:Gender,:Nationality,:Hand_Used)";

             QSqlQuery qry;

             qry.prepare(sQuery);
             qry.bindValue(":W_Id",122);
             qry.bindValue(":W_Name","fgdgd");
             qry.bindValue(":Age",32);
             qry.bindValue(":Gender",'F');
             qry.bindValue(":Nationality","gfdg");
             qry.bindValue(":Hand_Used",'R');

      if( !qry.exec(sQuery) )
          qDebug() << qry.lastError().text();
      else
        qDebug( "Inserted!" );
    }
             else
            {
                  qDebug() <<"Connection failed" << db.lastError().text();
        }

 db.close();
 return a.exec();

     }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I believe you don't have the database in the location that your application is trying to access it OR you really don't have the table called `Writers` in your database.

Comment: Why are you loading the SQLITE driver if you're trying to access an Oracle database?

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your help. @Vite Falcon: I'm sure the table is in the database,but when i create the table i didn't create my own database first, i used the default database of oracle 11g. do you think that this is the problem ??

Comment: I think the question that @Mat asked is relevant here... Why're you using SQLite driver to connect to Oracle database? SQLite is a file-based database like MS Access. So when you say connect to database ORCL, it's looking for a file called ORCL and _not_ trying to connect to your Oracle 11g database.

Comment: Thank you very much vite Falcon.. now i got the point.                    Could you please tell me which driver i can connect my oracle to it.

Comment: I solved the problem :) i installed and configured QODBC driver and used it in the place of SQLITE. Now i can see my tables. Thank you very much Guys. :D

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use `SQLITE` driver if you're trying to access an Oracle database.

`SQLite` is a file-based database like MS Access. So when you say *connect to database ORCL*, it's looking for a file called **`ORCL`** and not trying to connect to your Oracle 11g database.

### Solution:

Install and configur ***`QODBC`*** driver and used it in the place of ***`SQLITE`***.

After that the tables should be viewable.